# On a particular continued fraction related to $\pi$.

Tags: continued-fractions, means

Is this continued fraction well studied?

$$\Theta(m)=m+\cfrac{1^2}{2m+\cfrac{3^2} {2m+\cfrac{5^2}{2m +\cfrac{7^2}{2m+\cfrac{9^2}{2m+\ddots}}}}}$$

Note $\Theta(1)=\frac4\pi$.

Denote $\Theta(m)=\frac4{c_m}$.

With this notation $c_1=\pi$ which has an AGM procedure.

Is there an arithmetic geometric mean technique general $c_m$?

Comment: Why are there two parameters to your function when the only way they're used in the definition is multiplied together?

Comment: Why do you need an AGM procedure for this, the continued fraction seems to be a better way to compute this function

Comment: AGM is faster much much faster that is why Gauss invented it.

Comment: @Turbo, it involves taking square root. It can be much slower if you do it by hand

Comment: @Yuriy that would be fine. AGM is fastest technique for pi provided we have unlimited word size.

Comment: @Turbo, see [this paper](http://www.emis.de/journals/EM/expmath/volumes/13/13.3/BorweinCrandallFee.pdf), I think it's your continued fraction exactly

Comment: @YuriyS you mean one in abstract? no. I have seen this. It does not help.

Comment: This CF is evaluated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2093499).