# How to represent this quotient of gamma functions as a continued fraction

Tags: recurrence-relations, gamma-function, continued-fractions

I want to ask how to represent the following quotient as a continued fraction. I think we may use Gauss continued fraction but I am not too confident about it.

$\dfrac{\Gamma(x + \frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(x + 1)}\tag{1}=\cfrac{a_{1}}{b_{1}+}\cfrac{a_{2}}{b_{2}+}\cfrac{a_{3}}{b_{3}+}\cdots$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Up to a $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ term, the LHS is a Beta function. Have a look here: http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/10/

Comment: See [Conjectured general continued fraction for the ratio of gamma functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739431/conjectured-general-continued-fraction-for-the-quotient-of-gamma-functions) and also [Ramanujan's continued fraction for ratio of gamma values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093499/ramanujans-continued-fraction-for-ratio-of-gamma-values?rq=1) which may shed some light