# How to prove, that this chain fraction equals $\frac{4}{\pi}$?

Tags: number-theory, pi, continued-fractions

I would like to ask how do I prove this chain fraction equality?
\begin{equation}
  \frac{4}{\pi} = 1+{\raise{-0.8ex}\mathop{\huge\mathrm{K}}_{n=1}^{\infty}}\left[\frac{(2n-1)^2}{2}\right]= 1+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{9}{2+\cfrac{25}{2+ \ddots}}}
\end{equation}
Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/amm_supplements/Monthly_Reference_11.pdf

Comment: This book might also be helpful: http://www.gimnazija-izdijankoveckoga-kc.skole.hr/upload/gimnazija-izdijankoveckoga-kc/multistatic/387/EleAna.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2093499).