# Show continuity of $\sqrt{1-x} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{\sqrt{k}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Show that the function $f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}$
$$
f(x):=\sqrt{1-x} \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{x^k}{\sqrt{k}}
$$
is well-defined and continuous at the point $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Suppose that $a(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n x^n$ and $b(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n x^n$ converge when $|x|<1$, all $b_n$ are positive, and $\lim\limits_{x\ \uparrow\ 1}b(x)=\infty$. If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{b_n}=\lambda$ exists then $\lim\limits_{x\ \uparrow\ 1}\dfrac{a(x)}{b(x)}=\lambda$.

For a proof, replacing $a(x)$ with $a(x)-\lambda b(x)$, we may assume that $\lambda=0$. Now if $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, and $|a_n/b_n|<\varepsilon$ when $n>N$, then for $0<x<1$
$$\left|\frac{a(x)}{b(x)}\right|\leqslant\frac{1}{b(x)}\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n x^n\right|+\varepsilon\underset{x\ \uparrow\ 1}{\longrightarrow}\varepsilon,$$
i.e. $\limsup\limits_{x\ \uparrow\ 1}|a(x)/b(x)|\leqslant\varepsilon$. As $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, we have $\lim\limits_{x\ \uparrow\ 1}\big(a(x)/b(x)\big)=0$ as claimed.

Now apply the above to
$$a(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{n}},\quad b(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}-1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}x^n.$$
We have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{\pi}$ by [Wallis formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product), thus $\lim\limits_{x\ \uparrow\ 1}f(x)=\sqrt{\pi}$ as well.

[For the "previous version" we get $\lim\limits_{x\to\pi/2}f(x)\cos x=1$ the same way.]

Comment: Thanks a lot again @metamorphy !
I think that answers the question. Just to make sure about notation:
$(2n)!! := 2 * 4 * 6 * 8 * ... * 2n$ and
$(2n-1)!!:= 1 * 3 * 5 * 7 * ... * (2n-1)$

Comment: Some comments on the proof:
How is the power series for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ derived?
And as I see it, the proof is still valid if the power series of $b(x)$ starts at $n=0$. So we can in fact define $b(x):= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ without adding $-1$.

Comment: Is there any reference for the proof or does it go back to you?

Comment: The series is just a [binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) one, with $(-1)^n\binom{-1/2}{n}=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$ easy to verify. As for the reference, I didn't manage to find one. I think it should be hanging out of something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_and_tauberian_theorems). (I proved it myself long time ago, to use as a tool for evaluating some continued fractions.)

Comment: Thanks again for your solution! Very nice one